# How to get album image from mp3 file using ffmpeg in php

Tags: php

I want the album image from mp3 files. I have using ffmpeg for get the mp3 files metadata using

***ffprobe -show_format path-name***.

In this command i have get the all details except album image. How can i get the image from Mp3 files?

Comment: Maybe a lead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592709/retrieve-album-art-using-ffmpeg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the image from an mp3 using the following code snippet, try this..

```
ffmpeg -ss 125 -i wrong-way-fixed.mp3 -t 1 \ -s 480x300 -f image2 /dev/null
```

or use this

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -an -vcodec copy cover.jpg
```

You can define the image resolution here..