# Is it possible to get bitmap(Album art) from mp3 file or file inputstream?

Tags: android

Is it possible to retrieve bitmap( Album art ) of mp3 file from it's file path or file input stream. Like using BitmapFactory API or some other API.

Comment: Have you checked this.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592709/retrieve-album-art-using-ffmpeg

Comment: It is seems good. Don't we have any android API?

Comment: I am pretty sure there is none. In one of my prior projects i had to drill down in FFmpeg for something similar.

Comment: Yup.. thanks you have saved my time. Please write it in answer panel. I will mark it as right answer. so that it will be helpful to others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract album art from an mp3 file, there is no direct API available in Android as of now. You need to extract it via FFmpeg for the same.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is possible to get mp3 cover art.

```
MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
mmr.setDataSource(mPath);
InputStream inputStream = null;
if (mmr.getEmbeddedPicture() != null) {
    inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(mmr.getEmbeddedPicture());
 }
mmr.release();

bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
```

Comment: whats this line for..."BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
"

Answer (score 4):

Using the following method you can get the album art uri of an image file.

```
public Uri getArtUriFromMusicFile(File file) {
        final Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        final String[] cursor_cols = { MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID };

        final String where = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + "=1 AND " + MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + " = '"
                + file.getAbsolutePath() + "'";
        final Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, cursor_cols, where, null, null);
        Log.d(TAG, "Cursor count:" + cursor.getCount());
        /*
         * If the cusor count is greater than 0 then parse the data and get the art id.
         */
        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            Long albumId = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID));

            Uri sArtworkUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
            Uri albumArtUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, albumId);
            cursor.close();
            return albumArtUri;
        }
        return Uri.EMPTY;
    }
```

Comment: Kartheek.. i have my files in network. So i can't use your code

Comment: thanks, but doesn't work for all files: `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "s": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT album_id FROM audio WHERE (is_music=1 AND _data = '/storage/emulated/0/Music/Marked/2013 Gordon & Doyle vs Scooter- Let's Go Biz (Tr-Meet & Yuliana Mash-up).mp3')`

Comment: I guess it's because of `'` symbol in filename, do you know how to fix it?

Comment: this could help `path = path.replaceAll("'", "''");`