# Get Album Art of a music using ffmpeg in Webp

Tags: javascript, python, linux, audio, ffmpeg

I am struggling to output thumbnail of an mp3 file in webp format

Tried this but it did not worked for .webp

I am running this command in AWS lambda function to extract album Art and save in S3.

`ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -an -vcodec copy cover.webp`

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Reference: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592709/retrieve-album-art-using-ffmpeg)

Comment: By using the `-vcodec copy` flag, you're telling ffmpeg that you want to copy the codec that the video stream is using (in this case mjpeg), but you're then telling it to turn into a webp. As it's telling you, `Only WebP is supported`, as in, webp is webp, not mjpeg. You might be able to use something like `-c:v libwebp` instead to tell ffmpeg to turn the stream mjpeg into webp.

Comment: ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -an -c:v libwebp output.webp Worked!